# Unit conversions between g, ml, oz, etc.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, definition, unit-of-measure

Apologies if this is not appropriate for this site or too simple for the members here but I am not great with this.

If I have something measured in ml, can I convert it to grams by assuming 1g -> 1ml?

If I have something measured in oz, can I convert it to grams by assuming 1 oz -> 28.3495 grams? Or is there a difference between "ounce" and "fluid ounce"?

Having trouble telling these things apart and what conversions make sense and which do not.

Comment: But grams is about mass, while ml is about volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grams are mass and milliliters are volume.  1 ml of something very dense will weigh much more than 1 gram.  You need to multiply by density to make the conversion and the units will tell you that.  To go from length$^3$ to mass you need to multiply by something that has units $\frac {\text{mass}}{\text{length}^3}$ and the density is that.

Avoirdupois ounces are a unit of mass as are grams, so you can just use the conversion factor you quote.  Fluid ounces are a unit of volume, about $29.57$ ml.  There are also Troy ounces, used for things like gold, that are units of mass but different from the avoirdupois ounce.

Comment: So avoirdupois ounces are the only things I can "directly convert" to grams, whereas fluid ounces and ml require density to get something more accurate?

Comment: Troy ounces or any other mass measure (carats, stones, hundredweight, etc) can be directly converted to grams.  Volume measures need the density factor.